# Permission denied by sticky bit setting hive execution failing

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

When I try to fire a sql command in the process of forming a bucket table 
I am getting the below error , I understant that since process that is executing is hive but the /tmp is owned by mapred it is causing the issue. but I dont know how to fix the issue where should I change exactly.
please help me folks

```
 Permission denied by sticky bit setting: user= ras, inode=bucked_sample
Failed with exception Unable to move sourcehdfs://roax:8020/tmp/hive-training/hive_2016-02-16_03-29-10_837_2599907748984819467-1/-ext-10000 to destination /user/hive/warehouse/bucked_sample
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched
```

:

Comment: How do you check the user rights? Are you validating your local file system tmp file or the tmp dir on hdfs?

Comment: i was referring to mapreduce.cluster.local.dir ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local which  is configured to my local system /tmp

Answer (score 0):

The sticky bit setting on a directory prevents users from deleting files
they don't own.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please read "How do I write a good answer?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer